# Как вывести список от 1 до N в ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

Как можно (можно ли) вывести средствами XAML (без кода) в любой набор итемов (ListBox, например) числа от 1 до N? Или в VM для этого придется создавать новое поле с перечислением?

Comment: Ну не обязательно следовать мантре: «вся логика только в VM». Вы можете заполнить список в code behind Вашего окна. Средствами XAML, насколько я знаю, это сделать не получится. Там же нельзя прописать цикл. Можно, конечно, вручную добавить N-ое количество цифр в список в разметке, но ради чего?

Comment: @ixSci, N неизвестно, кстати. Ну в xaml я могу определить числа, строки (`<system:string>`, например), может и массив можно?

Comment: Можете — `system:Array`, но дальше что? Как его заполнить?

Comment: А а каком виде известно `N`?

Comment: @VladD В виде поля класса

Comment: С полями глухо, к ним нет доступа через `Binding`. Свойство покатит?

Comment: @VladD, да да, я имел ввиду именно свойство )

Answer (score 3):

Если количество элементов известно, то в xaml можно определить Array

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
   Title="Window1" Width="300" Height="200">
   <Window.Resources>
     <x:Array Type="s:String" x:Key="arr">
        <s:String>s1</s:String>
        <s:String>s2</s:String>
     </x:Array>
   </Window.Resources>
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource arr}" />
</Window>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Если количество элементов меняется, то для создания необходимого количества элементов можно использовать метод Enumerate.Range, у которого второй параметр привязать к Slider'у.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="Window1" Width="300" Height="400">
    <Window.Resources>
      <ObjectDataProvider
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:linq="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core"
         ObjectType="{x:Type linq:Enumerable}" MethodName="Range"
         x:Key="en">
         <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>5</sys:Int32>
         </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
      <Slider Minimum="1" Maximum="9" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="1">
          <Slider.Value>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource en}" Path="MethodParameters[1]" 
              BindsDirectlyToSource="True" 
              UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
              Mode="TwoWay"
              Converter="{app:IntConverter}" />
          </Slider.Value>
        </Slider>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource en}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;
namespace WpfApplication1 {
  public class IntConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type trg, object parameter, CultureInfo ci) {
       return value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type trg, object parameter, CultureInfo ci) {
       if (value.GetType() == typeof(Double)) return (int)((double)value);
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider sp) {
       return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ну блин... оно известно на этапе выполнения )))

Comment: @iRumba _"известно на этапе выполнения"_ -- в таком случае: определить свойство в VM.

Comment: @Stack: Хм, определили, а дальше? Как к нему прибиндиться без конвертера?

Comment: @VladD _"Как к нему прибиндиться без конвертера?"_ -- в примере в ListBox выводятся строки s1 и s2.

Comment: @Stack: насколько я понял задачу: у нас есть динамически изменяемый в рантайме параметр `N` (лежит в свойстве VM). Мы хотим показать список (1 2 3 ... N) _динамического размера_. У вас размер статический, ровно 2 элемента, и я вообще не вижу зависимости от `N`. Или я неправильно понял ваше решение?

Comment: @VladD _"Мы хотим показать список (1 2 3 ... N) динамического размера"_ -- в вопросе про динамический N не сказано. но если так, то определять все в XAML - неудобно, лучше сделать как обычно: свойство в коде и привязку.

Comment: @Stack: Ну, в этом и сложность, что всё в XAML, так бы вопрос был тривиальным. В конвертере написать `return Enumerable.Range(1, N)`, и всё.

Comment: @VladD _"в этом и сложность, что всё в XAML"_ -- и сложно и много xaml. но можно. обновил ответ. но совсем без кода не получается. т.к. для привязки Slider'а нужен конвертер.

Comment: @Stack: Круто! Возможно, от конвертера можно избавиться, если поставить в цепочку ещё один `ObjectDataProvider` с методом `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: @VladD _"от конвертера можно избавиться, если поставить в цепочку ещё один ObjectDataProvider с методом Convert.ToInt32"_ -- как сделать цепочку - не знаю. если знаете, напишите отдельный вопрос-ответ. я добавил новый [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489148/196972) -- без конвертера, на основе метода в `x:Code`

Comment: @Stack: Сейчас попробую сделать цепочку.

Comment: @Stack: Цепочку создать не получилось, но я подумал, что у ТС параметр `N` целочисленный, так что необходимость в конвертере из `double` в `int` отпадает. Зато возникает вопрос, как надеть `Binding` на `N`, которое лежит в VM.

Comment: @VladD _"у ТС параметр N целочисленный, так что необходимость в конвертере из double в int отпадает."_ -- конвертер тут для Slider'а, т.к. он выдает double, а в Enumerable.Range надо int. но есть [способ без конвертера](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489148/196972). _"как надеть Binding на N, которое лежит в VM."_ -- сделать это надо только в XAML?

Comment: @Stack: Способ без конвертера видел (и поставил плюс). По поводу «надевания binding'а» — cудя по всему, да :) Смотрите, вы привязываете `Slider.Value` (которое доступно в XAML'е) Binding'ом логически говоря «в обратную сторону» — от источника данных к приёмнику, а не наоборот, как обычно. Для случая, когда источник данных находится вне XAML (то есть, `N` из VM), это наверное получится не так просто.

Comment: @VladD _"Для случая, когда источник данных находится вне XAML (то есть, N из VM), это наверное получится не так просто."_ -- но, как я понял, такой случай не рассматриваем, т.к. все должно быть только в XAML. как сказано в вопросе "(без кода)". хотя совсем без кода не получается.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте Databinding например вот так

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind taskManager.sections}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:TaskSection">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
                 </ListBoxItem>                                
           </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                        
</ListBox>
```

Этот вариант конечно хорош для ObservableCollection

А так, можно скриптом в цикле

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    forTest.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem().Content = i);
}
```

Comment: а что такое `taskManager.sections`? а `data:TaskSection`?

Comment: да в коде то я и сам смогу. Просто хотел в xaml сделать без кода

Comment: @iRumba taskManager.sections это список установленный в коде, а data:TaskSection класс, но такой вариант больше нужен когда нужно выводить текст, для простого списка чисел хватит просто сделать в цикле

Answer (score 1):

Если количество элементов меняется, и все должно быть только в XAML, то можно использовать `x:Code` -- чтобы определить метод для создания `IEnumerable<int>` на основе `double`, полученного из Slider'а.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
  Title="Window1" Width="300" Height="400">
  <Window.Resources>
    <x:Code>
      public static object GetItems(double v) {
         return System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, Convert.ToInt32(v));
      }
    </x:Code>
    <ObjectDataProvider 
       xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
       MethodName="GetItems" 
       ObjectType="{x:Type app:Window1}"
       x:Key="items">
       <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
         <s:Double>0</s:Double>
       </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <Slider Minimum="1" Maximum="9" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickFrequency="1">
      <Slider.Value>
        <Binding 
           Source="{StaticResource items}" 
           Path="MethodParameters[0]" 
           BindsDirectlyToSource="True" 
           UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
           Mode="OneWayToSource" />
      </Slider.Value>
    </Slider>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```